# Finding induced magnetic field strength given current.

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, induction

I'm working on a project involving a Tesla Coil, and I was hoping to figure out how strong an induced magnetic field would be with an input voltage of X. Is there an equation to help solve this? I'm only in high school and haven't had any formal training.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using input voltage X and resistance of the coil R, you can get the current through the coil $I=\frac XR$. With current, number of coil, and length of the coil, you can get the magnetic field $B=\mu_0 \frac{IN}{L}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a name to this formula?

Comment: Magnetic field of a solenoid. Note this is an approximation using amperes law, and  its only valid inside the solenoid